# Testing content of Django.contrib.messages for invalid forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-contrib

I'm trying to test the content of messages while processing ModelForms with Django. I've got the following View (assume there's a `Thing` model with a required `name` field):

```py
@login_required
def update(request, thing_id):
    thing = Thing.objects.get(id=thing_id)  # assume this works

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ThingModelForm(request.POST, instance=thing)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Success!")
            return redirect("/wherever")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Oops!")
    else:
        form = ThingModelForm(instance=thing)

    args = ("myapp/update.html", {"form": form})
    kwargs = {"context_instance": RequestContext(request)}
    return render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, I've got two unit tests. The first tests valid data, while the second tests invalid data. (Note that client login happens during `setUp`):

```py
def test_update_account(self):
    url = reverse('update', args=[1])  # assume that's a valid id
    resp = self.client.post(url, {"name": "foo"})
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)

    m = resp.cookies.get('messages', '')
    self.assertTrue("Success!" in m.output())
```

And now to test invalid data:

```py
def test_update_account_failure(self):
    url = reverse('update', args=[1])  # assume that's a valid id
    resp = self.client.post(url, {"name": ""})  # name is required
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)

    # This works:
    self.assertTrue("Oops!" in resp.content)

    # This fails:
    m = resp.cookies.get('messages', '')
    self.assertTrue("Oops!" in m.output())
```

Why would accessing the message's content through the cookie work in one instance but fail in another?

Comment: For the record I'm using Django 1.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you could check:

1. When you create the request `self.client.post(url, {"name": ""})` is a Thing instance returned here: `thing = Thing.objects.get(id=thing_id)` If not it will not reach the line of code where you set your error message: `messages.error(request, "Oops!")` as Thing.objects.get will throw an [error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).

> If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a
>   DoesNotExist exception.

1. If the first thing does return a Thing instance, you could check whether a redirect return `redirect("/wherever")` after setting the error message `messages.error(request, "Oops!")` does change anything.

Comment: I do know that the ``Thing`` instance exists (I actually removed the code checking for this, so the example would be shorter), so for this question I'm not worried about raising a ``DoesNotExist`` exception.

Comment: If I understand your second comment correctly, in that scenario, I want to re-display the bound form if it doesn't validate; If I redirect after setting the "Oops" message that wouldn't happen.

Comment: That's correct, but I would suggest to try it and see whether your test passes. This would mean that Django returns the message in a cookie when a redirect happens, and returns the message in the context for "normal" responses. If this assumption proves correct, then you have to change the assert in your testcase, as the test case tests something that will never happen.

Comment: I see what you're saying, so I tested this and you are correct.  Django puts messages in a cookie when redirecting, but includes the messages in the content of 200 response. Thanks!